# How to update Bios of old Intel Server Board

Tags: bios, motherboard

I've recently come in possession of an old Intel server board **(S5000VSA)** and to tell you the truth, the noise is a bit much for me. I was reading that if I flash a new bios it would let me choose the amount of fans I have in the chassis and some other things, and it could make some of the noise go away. The bios is not present on Intel's site, so I went and downloaded it from somewhere else. Seems like a legit file, it has intel documentation and all. Thing is that the procedure on Intel's page says to do something with a type of file and my zip doesn't have that file. I've also watched a YouTube video in where it says to flash 3 .bat files that they actually are present in my zip file. The problem comes when I go to the EFI shell on the bios and try to execute those 3 files. I get an error that none of them are batch files or are not recognized as internal or external commands. Does anyone have any experience with these boards? There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on the internet and some articles contradict each other. I'd really appreciate the help.
Thank you!

Comment: Paragraphs are your friend, please add line endings where they would belong.  This is a garbled mess to read.    Your information is far to vague. `my zip doesn't have that file` .. WHAT FILE? ..  `when I go to the EFI shell on the bios and try to execute those 3 files` more data about this too please.

Comment: What exactly is your question? A question asking if anyone has experience with that motherboard wouldn’t be a question that’s actually within scope.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.someone actually understood what I was asking and guided me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution was to format a drive with FreeDOS and put the contents of the zip file in it. From there I could successfully execute the batch files needed to perform the upgrade. It didn't solve the noise problem but the BIOS upgrade was done correctly

Answer (score 0):

EFI shell commands are different from Windows Batch commands, which could explain the "command not found" errors.  Some boards allow you to initiate a BIOS update from within windows by executing those CMD scripts as an administrator once you're logged in.

Alternatively in BIOS for this board there is a menu where you can initiate a BIOS update.  Make sure you have the files available unzipped.  I usually put them on a little thumb drive formatted with an old file system like FAT32 and the BIOS will automatically detect you have something plugged in and allow you to navigate to it for the upgrade.

Found the user guide also, which has some instructions for upgrading the BIOS.

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5000vsa/sb/d36977005_s5000vsa_userguide.pdf

Comment: That's very insightful, I thought the Efi shell and cmd commands were the same ones